# Laravel Backpack checklist array storing ids instead of name values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

[I made a checklist with the possible sizes of a certain product but its storing the ids instead of the specific size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2BGd.png)

[This is the size field display.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBSH2.png)

I have the size field code like this:

```
CRUD::addField([
        'label'     => 'Size',
        'type'      => 'checklist',
        'name'      => 'size',
        'entity'    => 'sizes',
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'model'     => 'App\Models\Size',
        'pivot'     => false,
    ]);
```

How do I change it to store the size's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a pivot table between merch and sizes and then changing the type of the column size.

```
$this->crud->addColumns( [
        [
            'label' => 'Sizes',
            'type' => "select_multiple",
            'entity' => 'sizes', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'name' => 'sizes',
            'attribute' => "name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => "App\Models\Size",
            'pivot'     => true,
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to give an array to the “options” attribute, instead of specifying “entity”, “attribute”, “model”, “pivot”.

The array elements should be [value => label], where the value is what will be stored in the db, the label is what is shown next to the checkbox.